# Como testar curl PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho um projeto hospedado em um servidor, porém pretendo fazer uma integração para um outro site usando o curl. Só que ao passar os valores vindas do nosso banco de dados, dá erro nesse site que pretendo fazer integração, dizendo que os dados estão incorretos. Esse site é do nosso grupo, mas está em um outro servidor. Fui informado que o problema pode ser que o PHP não está fazendo o request para o Curl, outros dizem que o problema está no Curl, mas quando dou uma olhada no info.php, o curl está ativo. Tem algum meio de testar a CURL.

Alguém sabe me informar o porque isso ocorre?

Comment: Poste o código pra sabermos se é um problema nele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria melhor se você mostrasse a parte do código que tá dando erro. Mas os erros comuns ao usar CURL é o fato de não estar instalado no servidor, a forma como se trata os dados e a configuração de SSL. Você pode tentar o seguinte:

Verifique se está instalado:

```
function _isCurl() {
    return function_exists('curl_version');
}
```

Na definição dos parâmetros coloque 0 (zero) para o SSL:

```
$ch = curl_init("URL_PARA_CONECTAR");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
...
```

Trate o resultado como um json array:

```
...
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($data, true); // o true indica que você quer o resultado como array
```

Um exemplo de configuração seria:

```
$valoresParaSubmeter = array('key1' => 'valor1', 'key2' => 'valor2');
$ch = curl_init("URL_PARA_CONECTAR");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $valoresParaSubmeter);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($data, true); // o true indica que você quer o resultado como array

var_dump($response);
```

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: Olá Paulo. A verificação da Curl retorna (1), mas quando dou var_dump, não retorna nada.

Comment: Se retorna 1 (true) significa que a curl está instalada. Tenta executar o código acima submetendo outra url que retorne um json. Ex.: site.com.br/arquivo.txt - Onde este arquivo é um código json simples. Como você disse que tem acesso aos dois servidores, tenta primeiro no mesmo servidor da aplicação solicitante e depois no servidor remoto. Obs.: Certifique-se que esteja mandando os valores na requisição exatamente como o outro site pede.

Comment: Fiz o teste no servidor onde está o código e trouxe o resultado. Isso quer dizer que o problema pode estar no outro servidor?

Comment: Isso mesmo ou os dados que o outro servidor está pedindo não estão sendo enviados corretamente. Após a linha `$data = curl_exec($ch);` execute `echo curl_error($ch);` para ver qual o erro que está acontecendo. Se houver algum posta aqui para investigarmos. Por boa prática no final de tudo adicione a linha `curl_close($ch);` para liberar os recursos.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho muita paciência para utilizar as funções do  `Curl` do php, pois você acaba tendo que digitar muita coisa.

A minha sugestão é utilizar o `Guzzle`, que é uma biblioteca em PHP, que trata-se de um cliente para fazer requisições HTTP.

Você pode instalá-lo pelo `Composer`.

Daí eu utilizaria uma simples requisição:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$res = $client->get('https://u.github.com/user', [
    'params' => ['id' => 1]
]);
```

Se a requisição não tiver erros, você pode capturar  a resposta com um `echo $res->getBody()`.

Se a requisição falhar, uma Exception será lançada. Assim você poderá ver se há algo de errado com as requisições, ou até mesmo capturá-las.

```
try{

    $rest = $client->get('https://non-exists');

} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {

        var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody());
}
```

Comment: `GuzzleHttp` utiliza cURL para os requests. Ele apenas é uma biblioteca de poder de abstração e funcionalidade. Recomendar fazer uso dele sem ao menos saber utilizar a basica que é cURL pode acarretar em confusão e falta de experiência. Mas anyway, bela sugestão e examplo.

Comment: @juniorb2ss eu não sei se você compartilha da mesma opinião, mas tenho acho a forma de usar o curl (para um simples teste) mais confusa do que usar uma simples instância do Guzzle

Comment: Abstração é sim mais completo e de maior facilidade, porém, meu comentário foi a recomendação para alguém que não sabe os principios bases de cURL, compreende? Alias, Guzzle é ótimo e utilizo ele com frequencia.

Comment: Entendi sim. Obrigado pela suas colocações